# WordPress with Apppresser theme

Tags: css, wordpress

hello am kind of stack with CSS Am trying to archive this [how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Mx8.png)

and this [how it looks at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exKq3.png)

This is my current Header and footer CSS.
Can someone kindly help me to move the footer menu away from the footer and put it just right below the header and then insert a search bar in the header. I can provide the whole CSS file if need be, but have i have provided by current CSS for the header and Footer Below, Thanks in advance

```css
/* =Site Header
----------------------------------------------- */
.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #42ad54;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
  .site-header a, .site-header i {
    color: #fff; }

.ios7 {
  border-top: 20px solid #42ad54; }

.ios7 .site-header {
  top: 20px; }

.ios7.snapjs-left .site-header {
  top: 0; }

.site-title-wrap {
  max-width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.site-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin-top: .8em;
  text-align: center; }

.site-title, .site-title a {
  color: #fff; }

.site-description {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: none; }

#site-logo {
  display: block;
  max-height: 33px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto; }

.toolbar {
  padding: 10px; }

/* =Menus
----------------------------------------------- */
.top-menu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: .5em; }

.navigation-main ul, .top-menu ul, .sub-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0; }

.navigation-main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150%; }

.navigation-main a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

.navigation-main a i {
  margin-top: .3em;
  margin-right: .3em; }

.navigation-main li.current_page_item {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); }

.navigation-main li.current_page_item a {
  color: #f7f5ef; }

.top-menu ul a {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none; }

header .dropdown-menu ul a {
  color: #444; }

.navigation-main ul ul, .navigation-main ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  height: 150%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease; }

.sub-menu.open-sub-menu, .children.open-sub-menu {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease; }

.navigation-main ul ul a {
  width: 100%; }

.navigation-image, .navigation-comment, .navigation-paging {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em 0; }

header .nav-left-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.05em 1.1em .9em .9em;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: .8;
  margin-left: -.2em; }

header .back.nav-left-btn {
  padding-right: .3em; }

.nav-right-btn, header .widget_search a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .8;
  padding: 1.05em .9em .9em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.6rem; }

header .widget_search a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px; }

.app-panel .nav-right-btn {
  color: #fff; }

#app-panel-menu {
  position: relative; }

header .dropdown-menu a {
  color: #42ad54; }

header .sub-nav {
  background: #333;
  padding: 0; }
  header .sub-nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.4rem; }

header .sub-nav ul li.current_page_item a {
  background: #444; }

header .sub-nav ul ul {
  display: none; }

.navigation-main .nav-divider a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: #ccc;
  padding: .5em 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold; }

/* =Shelf Menu
----------------------------------------------- */
#page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Chrome and Safari */
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */ }

.snap-drawer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  width: 265px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  transition: width 0.3s ease; }

.snap-drawer-left {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1; }

.snap-drawer-right {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1; }

.snapjs-left .snap-drawer-right,
.snapjs-right .snap-drawer-left {
  display: none; }

.snapjs-expand-left .snap-drawer-left,
.snapjs-expand-right .snap-drawer-right {
  width: 100%; }

.shelf-top {
  width: 265px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; }
  .shelf-top .user-name {
    margin-top: 1.1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #eeeeee; }

.shelf-top .avatar {
  float: left;
  margin: .5em;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }

.shelf-search {
  padding: .5em; }

.shelf-search input {
  background: #777;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 250px; }

.cart-items {
  padding: 1.3rem 1.5rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #eeeeee;
  clear: both; }
  .cart-items i {
    float: left;
    margin-right: .6em;
    margin-top: .3em; }
  .cart-items .cart-contents {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #eeeeee; }
    .cart-items .cart-contents .amount {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-left: 1em; }

.log-out-button a {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px; }

/* =Item Panel
----------------------------------------------- */
.app-panel {
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 6;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f7f5ef;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease; }

.app-panel .product {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; }

.item-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; }

.app-panel .item-content {
  height: auto; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    .app-panel .item-content {
      height: 100%; } }

.open-panel body .app-panel {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease; }

/* Stages page transitions */
.stage-bottom .app-panel {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0); }

.stage-top .app-panel {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0); }

.app-panel #main {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: 0 3%;
  height: auto; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    .app-panel #main {
      height: 100%; } }

header.toolbar {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 3%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #42ad54; }

.toolbar .btn {
  margin: .8em 0 0;
  color: #fff; }

.ajax-spinner {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  opacity: .7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 56px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: -28px;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center; }

* =Site Footer
----------------------------------------------- */
.footer-widget-area {
  margin-top: 2em;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden; }

.site-footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background: #42ad54;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; }

.site-footer .widget {
  float: left;
  width: 22.5%;
  margin-left: 5%; }

.site-footer .widget:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 45%; }

.site-info {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
  text-align: center; }

.site-info, .site-info a {
  color: #999; }

/*** Footer Menu ***/
footer nav {
  height: 40px; }
  footer nav p {
    margin-bottom: 0; }

footer nav ul ul {
  display: none; }

footer .nav > li > a {
  padding: .8rem .3rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    footer .nav > li > a {
      padding: 1rem; } }

footer nav .fa {
  display: block; }

footer ul.nav-justified, footer ul.nav-tabs.nav-justified {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: horizontal;
  -moz-flex-direction: horizontal;
  -ms-flex-direction: horizontal;
  flex-direction: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center; }

footer .nav-justified > li, footer .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li, footer .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li, footer .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center; }

.has-footer-menu #main {
  margin-bottom: 40px !important; }
```

and then this is the footer code

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=main div and all content after
 *
 * @package AppPresser Theme
 */
?>

 </div><!-- #main -->
 <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'footer-menu' ) ) : ?>
 <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

  <nav class="footer-menu" role="navigation">
      <?php
       $args = array(
       'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
       'menu_class' => 'nav nav-justified' );
       wp_nav_menu($args);
      ?>
  </nav>

 </footer><!-- #colophon -->
 <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</div><!-- #body-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly the code for the header

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package AppPresser Theme
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="body-container">

<section class="snap-drawer">
 <div class="shelf-top">

 <?php appp_left_panel_before(); // Hook for search, user profile, and cart items ?>

 </div><!-- .shelf-top -->

 <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
  <div class="screen-reader-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'apptheme' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'apptheme' ); ?></a></div>
  <?php
  if( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) )
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
  ?>
 
 <?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
  <div class="log-out-button"><a class="btn btn-success btn-large noajax" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'Sign Out', 'apptheme' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Sign Out', 'apptheme' ); ?></a></div>
 <?php else: ?>
  <div class="log-out-button"><a class="btn btn-success btn-large noajax io-modal-open" href="#loginModal" title="<?php _e( 'Sign In', 'apptheme' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Sign In', 'apptheme' ); ?></a></div>
 <?php endif; ?>

 </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
 
</section>

<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
 <?php do_action( 'appp_before' ); ?>

 <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

  <section class="header-inner">

   <div class="pull-left">
    <?php do_action( 'appp_header_left' ); ?>
    <a href="#" class="nav-left-btn" id="nav-left-open"><i class="fa fa-reorder fa-lg"></i></a>
   </div>

   <div class="site-title-wrap">
    <?php do_action( 'appp_page_title' ); ?>
   </div><!-- .site-title-wrap -->

   <div id="header-widget-area">

    <?php
    do_action( 'appp_header_right' );

    if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) :
    $class = ( $icon = get_theme_mod( 'top_menu1_icon' ) ) ? $icon : 'fa fa-cog';
    ?>
    <nav id="top-menu1" class="top-menu pull-right" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-right-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <i class="<?php echo $class; ?> fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
     <?php
     $args = array(
      'theme_location' => 'top',
      'container_class' => 'dropdown-menu'
     );
     wp_nav_menu($args);
     ?>
    </nav>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top2' ) ) :
    $class = ( $icon = get_theme_mod( 'top_menu2_icon' ) ) ? $icon : 'fa fa-globe';
    ?>
    <nav id="top-menu2" class="top-menu pull-right" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-right-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="<?php echo $class; ?> fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
     <?php
      wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'top2',
       'container_class' => 'dropdown-menu'
      ) );
     ?>
    </nav>

   <?php endif; ?>

   </div>

  </section><!-- .header-inner -->

 </header><!-- #masthead -->

 <div id="main" <?php body_class( 'site-main' ); ?>>
```

Comment: Provide the code of header  Include footer code in header to bring footer up and for serach you need to write some hml code with wordpress serach function

Comment: Thanks i have added the code for the header and the footer